# Camera rotation in Three.js

Tags: three.js, rotation

I guess 3D calculation isn't easy to figure out with superficial knowledge about the subject.... :(

Any way, I have a scene like the one bellow with some objects at position R and a camera that may or may not be pointing to the objects. At some point I have to rotate the camera around the objects and it must remain at the same angle in relation to them. (Despite my 2D drawing the rotation is actually 3D)

[image]

Here is how I have rotated the camera (not sure it is the best method, but works):

```js
sphere = new Three.Spherical()
offset = new Three.Vector3()
offset.copy(camera.position).sub(R)
sphere.setFromVector3 offset
sphere.theta -= .......... the desired angles
sphere.phi -= .......... the desired angles
offset.setFromSpherical(sphere).add(R)
camera.position.copy(offset)
```

here I also tried to modify `camera.rotation` based on the two angles above but not even close to get the intended solution, mainly because I din 't figured out how to use the spherical data with the `Euler` used by the rotation.

Comment: You could make the camera a child of your center of rotation, which would allow you to apply camera manipulations locally to that object (reduces the complexity of rotation calculations). Also, your camera can use "lookAt" to, well, look at a target (`Vector3`). If you keep that `Vector3` orbiting in the same manner as your camera, then the look direction will also stay up-to-date. I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you need the camera rotation such that it's tangential along the circle cross-section (like the one you have in the image).

If the start and end position of the camera is A and B and midpoint of the circle is R.
So,

normal vector of the circle `N = crossVectors(A-R, R-B)`.

tangent vector at point `B` is `T = crossVectors(R-B, N)`.

You might have to check the direction of the vectors so that you are not looking the other way.

Then to orient the camera you can set the target to `B+T`(if using OrbitControls or similar) or use the `lookAt` function on the camera.

If instead of along the tangent, you want to keep it at the same offset angle from the original tangent:

Calculate tangent at both the points `A and` B, name them - `T1` and `T2`. Then make a quaternion from T1 to T2. `Q = new Quaternion().setFromUnitVectors(T1, T2).`
Now apply `Q` to the camera rotation. `camera.quaternion.multiply(Q)`.